# Hibernate auditing that stores only changed values

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I work on adding auditing functionality in Hibernate-based application.

Hibernate provides a very nice framework Envers, which can automatically create new auditing tables and populate them on every change. However, it means that for every single change it will copy all values, which can be very storage-consuming for application where data is changed frequently.

Would be nice to know about alternatives to Envers approach - the one that stores only **diffs** (changed columns and values). Maybe there's an existing out-of-box solution that's as tightly integrated with Hibernate and Spring Data as Envers. Or maybe it's not hard to write that without 3rd party libs.

Thanks!

Comment: If you would only save the changes you would need to know what exactly changed, which means on every save you would have to compare before and after of every single field of every object. While I can see the storage problem I feel like you would lose a considerable amount of performance for that task.

Comment: The comparison of before/after is already something that Envers does, so that's not too hard; however I would say the bigger question is how do you intend to store the diffs so that it can easily be queried and materialized for your business purposes.  The idea of Envers is to capture a "snapshot" of the entity so you can get entity instances back for each revision for a variety of purposes.  If you generate a diff and store this in some type of non-relational schema, then you do run into a potential performance problem needing to evaluate those diffs for similar queries that Envers provides.